# "Split" dataframe by month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has 5 columns. One of them is the column 'Day' that has the date of each register. It has many dates, from years ago until today.

for example (MM/DD/YYYY) format:

```
c1 c2 c3 day        c4
a  b  c  01-01-2018 d
e  f  g  01-02-2018 h
... more data from january 2018, then starting another month
i  j  k  02-01-2018 l
```

what I need to do:
I need to 'split' / 'select' the data for each month and upload it in a server. I am not sure how to do that. I thought in something like split the dataframe by month. How can I do this? I can give you another example if the question is not clear.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to split it by just month or month and year?

Comment: sounds like you want a groupby

Comment: just by month, I will send only month to the server. The years will be distinguished by folder.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use `groupby` with `Grouper`:

```
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2018-03-01'), columns=['Date'])
# groupby your key and freq
g = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='M'))
# groups to a list of dataframes with list comprehension
dfs = [group for _,group in g]
```

you can iterate over the list of groups for each month:

```
dfs[0]

       Date
0 2018-01-01
1 2018-01-02
2 2018-01-03
3 2018-01-04
4 2018-01-05
```

Comment: Chris, thank you very much! I was looking for this, it really solved my problem. I have just a question about the code: what the "_," before 'group' means?

Comment: that is just the variable I used to get ride of unneeded information so you can have a list of dataframes: `[Timestamp('2018-01-31 00:00:00', freq='M'). . .` it could be any variable you want: `[group for x,group in g]` you can see what it returns if you want: `[x for x,group in g]`. It is no different than a regular `for-loop`: `for x,group in g:`